# How to send JSON object to remote server and insert that data into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, sqlite

I am creating an iOS application that has a local SQLite database that users can add data too. I have a central MySQL database on a remote server that all the users can download and upload too. Currently I have the download part working. The part I can't find documentation on is sending the json object containing all the rows of my 5 tables to the remote server. I want to be able to parse the json object on the server, check if the primary key is in the table, if it isnt insert it, if it is skip. I am very new to this (php and objective c).

Do I just create a php script server side that does the above? How does it get the json object. I get how the sqlite gets the json object from the server because the php script is server side and thats where the mysql database is, but i cant wrap my head around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

[There's a JSON module for PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php).  The JSON should be the body of the request, so you just get the contents from the request and pass that to the JSON decoder.

[Here's an example](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/cookbook/json_request_body.html)